# Add per row the total value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014 I try to count a value per game per row like this:

[image]

Does anybody know if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old solution for this is to use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.Game, t1.Points, SUM(t2.Points) [Points (Add)]
FROM 
    yourTable t1 JOIN
    yourTable t2 ON t1.Game = t2.Game AND t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY 
    t1.id, t1.Game, t1.Points
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select [Order], Game, Points,
       sum(Points) over (partition by Game order by  [Order]) as CumePoints
from t;
```

You should avoid using reserved words and keywords for table or column names.  In other words, `Order` is a bad name for a column name, because it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and for the tip of avoid using "Order". It was just for the example.

Comment: I was under the impression this required windowing function (`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`). My head is spinning right now =)

Comment: @TT. . . . The windowing clause is occasionally required by some databases (Amazon AWS comes to mind).  However, it is not generally required.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i would have done it, if you would do it in T-SQL

```
if object_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL drop table #Temp

create table #Temp (id int, Game nvarchar(100), Points int)

insert into #Temp (id, Game, Points)
values
(1, 'A', 1),
(2, 'A', 2),
(3, 'B', 5),
(4, 'B', 5),
(5, 'C', 4),
(6, 'C', 8)

select id, 
   Game, 
   Points, 
   SUM(Points) over (partition by Game order by id) 
from #Temp
```